# Kali rolling vs kali sana repository

Tags: kali-linux, repository

Changing the source.list >> header to kali rolling repository.

Is kali rolling stable than kali-sana. I have some issues with kali sana old. Instalation of updates via kali-sana old repo was slower. Is it good to change header to the kali rolling? I fear if my system would crash. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to kali-linux documentation you should use the kali-rolling repository on your `sources.list`:

[What should my sources.list look like?](https://docs.kali.org/faq/kali-sources-list-faq)

> Kali rolling users should have these entries in their /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

> For a more in-depth description of possible entries in your sources.list, [check this post](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories).
>
> The Kali Rolling Repository
>
> kali-rolling is our current active repository since the release of Kali 2016.1. Kali Rolling users are expected to have the following entries in their sources.list:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

The kali sana is retired.

[**Transitioning From Kali 2.0 to Kali Rolling**](https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-rolling-edition-2016-1/)

> Migrating from Kali sana (2.0) to Kali rolling is simple. As root, you can run the following commands and be on your way:

```
cat << EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
EOF

apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade 
reboot
```

**Please note that the Kali sana repositories will no longer be updated and will be EOL’d on the 15th of April 2016.**