# Kali Linux not booting after update [bricked]

Tags: kali-linux

After not using kali for a long time (+/- 2 years) I decided to run it again. First thing I did was opening my terminal and updating kali using `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.
To my surprise it couldn't find any update. I checked my sources.list and found several lines, which I can't remember anymore. Deleted and replaced them with "*deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib*" according to the official website.
Opened the terminal again and entered the update command. It found a ton of updates, dpkg'd most of them and after half an hour updating was completed.

Rebooted my pc and encountered the following on boot up: [image]

Got the same result when trying to open recovery mode. 
What is the reason behind my bricked kali and how do I resolve my problem?

Comment: https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux Kali's page on this is quite good. Pay particular attention to the part about the restricted package set and repos, and the strong warning against adding other repos. Just the fact you had to change repos was really all the warning you needed.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you try:

[Switch to a TTY](https://askubuntu.com/a/66198) and run:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# reboot
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399845/313437